# How to pass a java class name as parameter and use it as casting in method

Tags: java, class, types, classname

I am trying to implement a general dialog method that every activity can call it. The public static method shall be something like this. But I have problem to cast mContent to its activity class name.

```
  public static void  openDialogEntry(Class activityClassName, Context mContext,  String title,  ... ) {
    Dialog_Entries   dialog = new Dialog_Entries(  title,   ...  );
    dialog.show( ((activityClassName) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
}
```

I want to call this method from fragments of any activity for example from  a fragment(view) of SecondActivity.java using

```
 openDialogEntry(view.getContext().getClass, view.getContext(),  title,  ... ) ;
```

What I expect to do is doing something like next line in openDialogEntry method

```
 dialog.show( ((SecondActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
```

It seems that `((activityClassName) mContext)`  is not working.
I want to call the public static method from MainActivity.java and ThirdActivity.java too (and their fragments which would need the casting).

How to realize this goal ?

Comment: The cast literally achieves nothing if Context already has a getSupportFragmentManager method.

Comment: What about if I called the method from a fragment of SecondActivity?  I need to cast it to access getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: Excuse me.  I call the method from a fragment of SecondActivity. Question is changed to make it clear.

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code to avoid this ping pong.

Comment: You want to call a static method? So mContext really has no use in this at all. You have the Class, then get the method through reflection and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Class has a method `Class.cast(Object)` that is you could do this:

```
public static void openDialogEntry(Class<? extends Context> activityClassName, Context mContext, String title, ...) {
    Dialog_Entries dialog = new Dialog_Entries(title, ...);
    dialog.show(activityClassName.cast(mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
}
```

Note that `cast` only makes sense when providing generic information on the `Class` parameter

However as @Zabuzard already mentioned. This makes not much sense. If you can cast `mContext` to `activityClassName` why not use this class instead of `Context` as method parameter?

`Context` probably implements some `interface` or extends some `class` that provides the `getSupportFragmentManager` method. So there is no need to cast at all.

Comment: Also they're trying to call a static method through an instance. They've determined that a cast is a way to achieve this.

Comment: @matt I added generics to the `Class` parameter. `openDialogEntry` is a static method, but `getSupportFragmentManager` is not. And `openDialogEntry` doesn't belong to `Context`. At least I can't find this information.

Comment: "getSupportFragmentManager is not" how do you know that? Then they dont even need the cast, just accept the argument as a context.

Comment: @matt I know. SoF... Why do you think `getSupportFragmentManager` is static?

Comment: Their last statement where they say "I want to call the public static..."

Comment: @matt I think this refers to `openDialogEntry`

Comment: I figured that's why they want to cast, because it is static. Otherwise inheritance would delegate.

Comment: Android studio does not like 
dialog.show(activityClassName.cast(mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);   The getSupportFragmentManager() is still red.  Is it  because getSupportFragmentManager is not a static method ?  If this is a problem, then I cannot realize the concept in a public static method.

Comment: @user2818066 please show the code where `getSupportFragmentManager` is defined and show the code of the `Context` class.

Comment: @dpr  ,  getSupportFragmentManager() is an android library in FragmentActivity.java .    The context class is too messy and too big to show here.   And the view is the inflated view of the fragment in SecondActivity.java.

Comment: @user2818066 where is the connection between `Context` and `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: view.getContext()   is the Context I passed.  And the 'view' is the inflated view of the fragment in SecondActivity.java.